# How can I write this XPath 2.0 query in XPath 1.0

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have a XPath 2.0 query (which seems to be ok and which returns the node I expect it to return) however, but I need to have it written in XPath 1.0. Is it possible and if yes how can I do it ?

**Info :**

What i want to do is to concatenate the `tokenValue` of all `IDENTIFIER` and `DOT` nodes below `qualifiedIdentifier` and select the `qualifiedIdentifier` nodes if this concatenation results in a String which starts with "another.pkg".

**The XPath 2.0 query :**

```
//importDeclaration/qualifiedIdentifier[starts-with(string-join(descendant::*/*/@tokenValue,''),'another.pkg')]
```

**The xml :**

```html
<compilationUnit tokenValue="package" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0">
  <packageDeclaration tokenValue="package" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0">
    <PACKAGE tokenValue="package" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0">
      <TOKEN tokenValue="package" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0"/>
    </PACKAGE>
    <qualifiedIdentifier tokenValue="my" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="8">
      <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="my" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="8">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="my" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="8"/>
      </IDENTIFIER>
      <DOT tokenValue="." tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="10">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="." tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="10"/>
      </DOT>
      <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="pkg" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="11">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="pkg" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="11"/>
      </IDENTIFIER>
    </qualifiedIdentifier>
    <SEMI tokenValue=";" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="14">
      <TOKEN tokenValue=";" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="14"/>
    </SEMI>
  </packageDeclaration>
  <importDeclaration tokenValue="import" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="0">
    <IMPORT tokenValue="import" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="0">
      <TOKEN tokenValue="import" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="0"/>
    </IMPORT>
    <qualifiedIdentifier tokenValue="another" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="7">
      <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="another" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="7">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="another" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="7"/>
      </IDENTIFIER>
      <DOT tokenValue="." tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="14">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="." tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="14"/>
      </DOT>
      <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="pkg" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="15">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="pkg" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="15"/>
      </IDENTIFIER>
      <DOT tokenValue="." tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="18">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="." tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="18"/>
      </DOT>
      <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="AnotherClass" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="19">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="AnotherClass" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="19"/>
      </IDENTIFIER>
    </qualifiedIdentifier>
    <SEMI tokenValue=";" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="31">
      <TOKEN tokenValue=";" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="31"/>
    </SEMI>
  </importDeclaration>
  <typeDeclaration tokenValue="public" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="0">
    <modifier tokenValue="public" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="0">
      <PUBLIC tokenValue="public" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="0">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="public" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="0"/>
      </PUBLIC>
    </modifier>
    <classDeclaration tokenValue="class" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="7">
      <CLASS tokenValue="class" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="7">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="class" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="7"/>
      </CLASS>
      <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="AClass" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="13">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="AClass" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="13"/>
      </IDENTIFIER>
      <classBody tokenValue="{" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="20">
        <LWING tokenValue="{" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="20">
          <TOKEN tokenValue="{" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="20"/>
        </LWING>
        <RWING tokenValue="}" tokenLine="6" tokenColumn="0">
          <TOKEN tokenValue="}" tokenLine="6" tokenColumn="0"/>
        </RWING>
      </classBody>
    </classDeclaration>
  </typeDeclaration>
  <EOF tokenValue="" tokenLine="6" tokenColumn="1"/>
</compilationUnit>
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tokenization is always the same, you can just concatenate the first three tokens:

```
 //importDeclaration/qualifiedIdentifier[concat((.//*/*/@tokenValue)[1],
                                                (.//*/*/@tokenValue)[2],
                                                (.//*/*/@tokenValue)[3])='another.pkg']
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to do it in XPath 1.0 that's as general as the 2.0 version, you'd have to be much more specific, e.g. check if the *first three* tokens are `another`, `.` and `pkg` respectively

```
//importDeclaration/qualifiedIdentifier[*[1]/*/@tokenValue = 'another']
                                       [*[2]/*/@tokenValue = '.']
                                       [*[3]/*/@tokenValue = 'pkg']
```

This is slightly stricter than your 2.0 version, to be exactly equivalent you'd have to check that the third token *starts with* `pkg` instead of being *equal to* `pkg` (allowing `"another.pkgfoo"`, for example, though this may not in fact be desirable).

Comment: Thank you, this works fine, however my string is ways longer than in my example, that's why i selected choroba's answer.